# Spring Security: put additional attributes(properties) in the session on success Authentication

Tags: spring, session, authentication, spring-security

Just simple question: what is the best way to add attributes(properties) to the  HttpSession on success authentication? The userID for example.

For now i'm using my own SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implementation in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and doing it like this:

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        PersonBean person = (PersonBean) auth.getPrincipal();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("currentUserId", person .getId().toString());
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);
```

But I dont think this is good approach as there is another ways to do authentication(RememberMe for example).

So what do I need to use here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was given on spring forum. [Link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123358-Put-additional-attributes%28properties%29-in-the-session-on-success-Auth&p=402440#post402440).

Generally, need to implement an ApplicationListener which listens for succes events and put additional attributes in the session there.

But in my case its not required to store attributes in the session. I can retrieve userID like here:

```
var userId = ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal.id}
```

Answer (score -1):

Spring does all this for you, you'll have to create a table *persistent_logins*, here is a snippet from app context that might help. And the official doc's lay [describe in detail](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) what is required :

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <security:form-login login-page="/Login"
     authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
     authentication-failure-url="/Login?login_error=1" />
  <security:remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource"
    user-service-ref="myUserService" />
</security:http>
```

and then you can access the principal object from your anywhere in your app, eg below shows the tag to output username in jsp :

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />
```

and from your java code this can be done :

```
MyUser user = (MyUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Comment: The persistent_logins table doesn't really have anything to do with storing attributes in the session. That's just a particular remember-me implementation. It does makes sense to store additional custom user attributes in the authentication object though.